# Is there any common name for this type of shot?

Tags: cinematography, terminology

When a character makes a decision to do something, we see actors looking down and then blinking and looking forward at the same time. I think I often see this in English dramas.

Is there a name given to this specific shot?

It wasn't strictly drama, but the first thing I thought of was the Metal Gear scene:

| [image: Solid Snake looking down pensively] | [image: Solid Snake looking into the 'camera' decisively] |
| --- | --- |

Comment: If there is none it should be "Decision Time Stare".

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeterminedExpression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a regular close-up. The 'shot' comes from the actor's performance, not from camera work.